# If $f$ is a continuous function on $\Bbb{R}$, then prove that $\int_0^1 f(x)x^2 \, \mathrm{d}x = f(c)/3$ for some $c \in[0,1]$.

Tags: definite-integrals

I tried to solve this using Riemann sum. I get integral is $f(c)c^2$ for some $c$ in $[0,1]$. But I couldn't show that it is $f(k)/3$ for some $k$ in $[0,1]$. Could you help me? Thanks.

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: Apply the mean value theorem for integrals https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem to the case $g(x) = x^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. Note that
$$\min_{t\in [0,1]} f(t) \cdot \int_0^1 x^2\,dx\leq \int_0^1 f(x)x^2\,dx \leq \max_{t\in [0,1]} f(t) \cdot \int_0^1 x^2\,dx.$$

Comment: Thanks,I got it.